# Writing a user-command with the same name as a built-in Stata command

Tags: stata

I would like to redefine a built-in command in Stata. Say for instance I want to add the  number of missing values after the `summarize` command. When I create a ADO file for a `program` called `summarize`, Stata automatically uses the built-in program instead of the user-written one. Is there a way to change this behavior?

Comment: This seems like a terrible idea. Why not just write a wrapper for summarize called something else?

Comment: @Dimitriy V. Masterov put concisely what I took 10 minutes to write.

Comment: I expected someone would answer this way. However, I don't see the harm in returning one more scalar (for instance adding the number of missing observation to summarize), especially if it takes the form of a supplementary option like summary varlist, missing. This forces me to memorize new names and makes my code basically unsharable with other people.

Comment: If your code relies on the extra scalar, then the code would be unsharable anyhow (unless you also gave your program). What is worse, it would be very hard for that new person to diagnose why code isn't running. If the program has a different name (say summarize2), (s)he would quickly find out that that program is missing and ask you where to find that program and the problem is solved.

Comment: You can also define summarize2.ado in the do-file that you share, which makes it very portable.

Comment: Ok I understood your point. However, my will was just to change the output displayed by the command. If StataCorp reads me, adding the option missing to the command summarize that shows missing observations, and adding the option order to the command sort that orders the varlist after sorting it would be useful!

Comment: Note also that in this case `summarize` is built-in code, i.e. part of the executable, so even in principle you cannot modify it. StataCorp must speak for themselves, but I think they would point to `codebook` among other commands documenting missings. Ultimately, however, writing your own eclectic commands is the direct way to get what you want, and there are thousands of user-written commands in the public domain as illustration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the case of key commands like `summarize` the answer is not even to think about doing it. Even if you found an ado file with the same name and replaced it with your own that behaved differently, the odds are that you would break Stata and make something of your own that worked unpredictably and with far more errors. `summarize`, with or without you knowing it, is called by many other programs.

You would not get much support from anybody in working out what you messed up except advice to reinstall.

In fact I wouldn't try to overwrite **anything** written by StataCorp.

Writing your own programs that add something extra is in contrast a very good idea.

In case anyone makes unfavourable comparisons with other software in which all the code is visible, the details are different but the principle is much the same. It would, for example, be very foolhardy to think about changing the deepest parts of R unless you had very full understanding of what you were doing.

Comment: The main difference is not whether the code is visible, but whether redefining a function changes it everywhere. Redefining sd in R does not break anything. http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html

Comment: Is that one of the "deepest parts"?

Comment: What do you mean? My question asked whether I could name a user written command the same as a command written by StataCorp. Your answer was that it was no possible, since it would change other functions that call summarize, right?

Comment: Maybe the question title should be "writing a new command with the same name as an existing command"

Comment: Some official commands **cannot** be replaced by user-written commands because they are defined by the C code and no user-written command can trump that. Other official commands defined by ado and/or Mata code could be replaced by user-written commands but in general that's **not a good idea**. There is no one-word answer that fits: "can't" and "shouldn't" would both be seriously incomplete. If you want to revisit the question, please edit in your additions or revisions.